# KARAF : How to get a web context path from a bundle?

Tags: jetty, apache-karaf

I have an osgi apllication deployed on an apache Karaf (Felix) plateform.
The application use Jetty as a web container.
Now i want to know if there is way to get the web context path used in the application using a simple bundle.
Is there any http service to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karaf by default exposes an OSGi service through the [WebContainerService](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/web/WebContainerService.java) interface which allows you to get the contextPath of a WebBundle using it's id.

You can consume that service within your bundle, using blueprint, Declarative Services, etc.